# Adding dynamically a sharding key in ArangoDB

Tags: database, indexing, sharding, arangodb

I'm installing a clustered db with **ArangoDB**. I need use indexes in collections.

We suppose that we have one collection named `myCollection` that was created with the shard keys `_key`.

Let `myVariable` be the unique key of `myCollection` so I have a unique constraint on `myVariable`.

By `myCollection` is created, and data are inside.

I don't want erase all, create `myCollection` again and add a new shard key with `myVariable` and restore `myCollection`, so I need to add a new shard key dinamically meanwhile that `myCollection` is already created.

Is this possible? Can I add, somehow, new shard key?

I mean, add key in `_shardBy` label without recreate collection.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, changing the shard key after creation is not supported. If you take a look at the consequences this would have, its easily understandeable why:

The shard key identifies to the coordinator which documents should end on which cluster node. Vice versa it can therefore predict where to search for documents based on the shard key. This assumption would fail if you change that condition to an arbirtary new one. Therefore documents not matching the condition would have to be moved to the correct new shard.

As you see, you need to work with all documents anyways. So if you don't want to download all data to the client, some javascript on the coordinator like a Foxx Service could fill the gap:

- create the new collection with the proper shard key
- fetch all `_key`s into memory
- issue repetive AQL queries that select a range from the old collection and insert it into the new one.

You may want to start an additional coordinator if you don't want to use your existing setup for this.

Hint: An upgrade to ArangoDB 3.0 will require a dump/restore cycle anyways - so if you can postpone your problem a little you may solve it then.